# Show that a linear transformation exists where a inversible transformation is given

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations

I've been trying to solve this issue:

> Let $V$ be a finite vector space, and let $S:V\rightarrow V$ be an inversible linear transformation.
>
> Show that a linear transformation, $T:V\rightarrow V$, exists where: $ker TS = \{0\}$ but $ker T \ne \{0\}$

Given the information, we know that $S$ is isomorphic, and there exists $S^{-1}$ which for each $v \in V$ makes $SS^{-1}(v) = v$ and $S^{-1}S(v) = v$.

And also we know that the kernel of the $S$, it being isomorphic. So, $ker S = \{0\}$.

How can I show the kernel of $ker TS \ne \{0\}$?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: But I cannot give a simple answer such as $T(v)=...$ fulfills the condition. I must develop the given information into a general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true: if $v\in\ker T$ nonzero then $S^{-1}v\ne 0$ and $S^{-1}v\in\ker TS$.

Comment: Please let me see if I understand, given a $v\in ker T$ and $v \ne 0$, then there is a vector $u\in V$ that makes $S^{-1}(u) = v$ and that vector is in $ker TS$?

Comment: No, $u$ should be $S^{-1}v$, i.e. it should make $Su=v$. Then $u\ne0$ and $TSu=Tv=0$.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. Great explanation!